# Fixed size of detail block regardless of row count

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to design an invoice where the detail block with rows of data will be fixed size. I'm using *iReport 5.6*. After the detail block, there will be subtotals and totals. A detail block can span multiple pages. Anyone got any idea? I am new to *iReport*. I tried myself and searched a lot. But no luck. Can anyone help me please?

Here is a sample invoice.

[image]

I am trying to make a table like this.

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514706/need-table-fixed-size-detail-block
This seems to be a solution of my problem. But I didn't get it actually. It's more than 7 years old.

Comment: Subtotal and total will show at all page or at last page?

Comment: Subtotal and total will show on the last page

Comment: I had the same problem, post a issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567870/how-can-i-get-a-sql-query-that-always-would-be-multiple-of-n and works fine for me!